# Study the convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n(x)= \frac{f(x)}{1+\frac{|f(x)|}{n}}$ (convergence in measure, pointwise and in $ L^2(R ^d)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

Study the convergence of the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)= \frac{f(x)}{1+\frac{|f(x)|}{n}}$$ (convergence in measure, pointwise and in $ L^2(\mathbb{R} ^d)$).

Let f be a measurable function such that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R} ^d)$

$$f_n(x)= \frac{f(x)}{1+\frac{|f(x)|}{n}}$$

My attempt:

1) $\{f_n\} \to f(x)$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^d$

2)Convergence in measure:

for all $\lambda>0$, by the Chebyshev's inequality:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} m \left( \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : |f_n-f|=\left|\frac{f(x)^2}{n+|f(x)|}\right|> \lambda \right\} \right)<\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{f(x)^2}{n+|f(x)|} $$

Now:

$$g_n(x)= \frac{f(x)^2}{n+|f(x)|} \to g(x)=0$$ pointwise on $\mathbb{R}^d$
and $f(x)^2$ dominates $g_n$ on $E$ in the sense that $|g_n|<f^2$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ for all $n$.

Therefore, by the lebesgue dominated convergence theorem:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{f(x)^2}{n+|f(x)|} =  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)^2}{n+|f(x)|}=0 \\ \implies \lim_{n \to +\infty} m(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : |f_n-f|> \lambda\})=0$$

I would be thankful if somebody tell me whether my attempt is correct or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct. Also, $L^{2}$ convergence follows similarly.
Note that

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert _{2}^{2} & = & \int\frac{f(x)^{4}}{\left(n+\left|f(x)\right|\right)^{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
But since $\frac{f(x)^{4}}{\left(n+\left|f(x)\right|\right)^{2}}\to0$
pointwise and since 
$$
\frac{f(x)^{4}}{\left(n+\left|f(x)\right|\right)^{2}}\leq f(x)^{2}\in L^{1}
$$
then again by dominated convergence we get that $\left\Vert f_{n}-f\right\Vert _{2}^{2}\to0$.